# Turing-independent joins

Tags: set-theory, computability-theory

Define $Y \subseteq 2^{\omega}$ to be  Turing independent if for every finite $F \subseteq Y$ and $y \in Y \setminus F$, the Turing join of $F$ does not compute $y$.

Define $X \subseteq 2^{\omega}$ to be good if $X$ is Turing independent and there is a function $A \mapsto y_A$ from $[X]^{\aleph_0}$ to $2^{\omega}$ such that each $y_A$ computes every member of $A$ and the family $\{y_A: A \in [X]^{\aleph_0}\}$ is Turing independent.

Question. Let $\kappa$ be least such that there is a Turing independent family of cardinality $\kappa$ which is not good. Does ZFC decide $\kappa$?

Comment: It is clear that $\kappa > \aleph_0$, isn't it? For any countable independent family, take a continuums-sized independent family above its join. I assume that your function $y_{\cdot}$ is to be injective? Beyond $\kappa > \aleph_0$, I'd guess we are in cardinal invariants territory, but I don't have an idea how to prove this.

Comment: MA$(\kappa)$ implies that every Turing independent set of size $\kappa$ is good.  Is it obvious that there exists a family which is independent but not good?